# How do I know if a type is a "Number" in runtime (without type classes)

Tags: scala

Let's say I don't have the option of using `[T: Numeric]` type class for some reason.

Is there a way given an "Any" to test if it is a "Number" without using the above?

**EDIT:** thanks to Lee's comment, it's apparently as easy as in Java: `x.isInstanceOf[Number]`.

My understanding of why it works is: `x:Any = 1` is basically in runtime a `java.lang.Integer` which in turn implements `java.lang.Number`

Comment: well, could you define "Number"?

Comment: `a.isInstanceOf[Number]`

Comment: @kaktusito - well, pretty much anything that implements the basic arithmetic methods... Very, very close to Numeric

Comment: @Lee you are a genious. Is it because in runtime like a Java boxed type which all implements Number?. Is that the magic that is happening here?

Answer (score 5):

```
val a = "hello"
val b = 1.34
toNumericOption(a) // None
toNumericOption(b) //Some(1.34)

def toNumericOption(x: Any) = x match {
  case n: java.lang.Number => Some(n)
  case _ => None
}
```

You can use this to convert to an Option